# Overriding css elements on responsive issue

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have a mobile menu on responsive, which use a javascript to show all of the elements from the menu. It puts on my `<ul>` a css code `display:block` on the **element**. So on a specific screen in my case:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:980px){
     ul {display:none}
}
```

If I want to override it with a display none, it doesn't work because the `display:block` it is **inline**. I tried to change it like this :

```
.myclass .myclass2 ul {display:none}
```

but still doesn't work. I do not want to touch the javascript. How can I override it ?

Comment: If its inline then you can use `[style]` `selector` as `.myclass .myclass2 ul[style] { display:none !important;}` and don't worry about `!important` as this `selector` only works when it has `inline-css`. So you dont have to go and write *CSS* again to override n all for this.

Comment: you should point the ul like `.myclass > .myclass2 > ul` in media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an inline style as you said `display:block` the single why to override this from within a CSS file is by using `!important`. But that wont work in your case if you want to show the menu at a click of a button.

I would use 2 classes for this, one to show the menu and one to hide it, no inline CSS and no `!important`. On window.onload/document.ready event I would take the width of the document and if its greater than `980px` I would add the hidden class  to hide the menu, when user clicks the menu button I toggle the show class. The same thing for window.resize event.